# Dlookup in access form to retrieve details not working

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

```
Private Sub RID_AfterUpdate()
Me.RTM = DLookup("RTM", "SSPTab", "[Recordid]='" & Me.Rid & "'")
End sub
```

Table name: SSPTab, Need value of RTM from SSPTab, Recordid is uniquevalue in table and RID is same value in userform, I want the value to be reflecting in userform once retrieved

Answer (score 0):

I guess RID is numeric, thus:

```vb
Private Sub RID_AfterUpdate()
    Me!RTM.Value = DLookup("RTM", "SSPTab", "[Recordid]=" & Me!Rid.Value & "") 
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the above code and I still get the error as 3075 "Syntax error missing operator in query expression '[recorded]='

Comment: RID is numberic...(autonumber)

Comment: Then either `Recordid` is misspelled or `Me!RID.Value` is _Null_.

Comment: One more point is It is showing the result as error now .....error 2471 ...The expression you entered as query parameter produced this error : RTM1234

Comment: RTM1234 is probably a value of yours, it is no error code, so double-check your data.

Comment: yes it is the value we needed, however instead of getting the value updated in userform it is popping out as error box

Comment: Something else is going on. There is no _query parameter_ here. Debug your form. Try setting `Me!RTM.Value` to a fixed value like `RTM1234`.

Comment: Dim str As Variant
str = Me!Rtm.Value
Str = DLookup("RTM", "SSPTab", "[Recordid]=" & Me!Rid.Value & "")
Me!RTM.Value = str

Comment: Still the same error not sure where am I missing

Comment: `str = 'RTM1234'`.

Comment: I didnt get you, and one, the values in the record id (Me.RID) are getting populated from table SSPtab. Can you please remodify code and send...Not able to get you

Comment: To be more clear Table has fields RTM, Recordid and the naming in userforms are RTM and RID... both refers the same and I want the userform to populate RTM value in userform whenever I change RID. When I initially created RID combo box I selected SSP tab reference Record ID as populating the values.

Comment: You miss to try setting a fixed value: `Me!RTM.Value = "RTM1234"`. If that works, revise your DLookup expression. If the ID field is named "Record ID", adjust your DLookup expression.

Comment: SELECT [SSPTab].[RTTM], [SSPTab].[Recordid] FROM SSPTab ORDER BY [Recordid], [RTTM];

Comment: This is in query field of RID

Comment: But then you can pull `RTTM` (if it is the same as `RTM`) directly from the combox ... no reason to look it up once more.

Comment: Basicall if someone submits form with certaing RTM#, then an RID will be created along with RTM # in table. Now when that person wants to go back and check the RTM with this RID number, it should autopopulate the value when he opens the combobox (RID) drop down

Comment: If so, you may have first to requery the combobox.

Comment: Nothing is working out

Comment: Then you are left with traditional debugging. Double-check everything. RTM=RTTM?